# How can I use module commands?

Tags: drivers, 20.04

I am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I need to use these commands :

$ module avail

$ module load gcc9.1.0

$ module load openmpi_4.0.1/gcc_9.1.0

but I face the error that I have not module command.
I need to help me with how I can install it or what things I should install to use module commands.

what should I do? also, I used this command :

$ Sudo apt-get install environment-modules

then I type $ module avail I receive :

module: command not found

Actually, I am installing the netCDF library from GitHub >>>(https://github.com/USEPA/CMAQ/blob/master/DOCS/Users_Guide/Tutorials/CMAQ_UG_tutorial_build_library_gcc.md)<<<

Comment: Who told you there was `module` command?

Comment: ... it's part of the `environment-modules` package (from the `universe` repo)

Comment: @ Pilot6.noone.I thought to myself maybe it is.

Comment: @ steeldriver.so what should I do?   also, I used this command Sudo apt-get install environment-modules but it didn't work. (I mean I have that error again)

Comment: I am a beginner at ubuntu and open source.

Comment: @FarzadFarzad it sounds like the instructions you are following are targeted at other Linux distributions and may not be appropriate for Ubuntu

Comment: @steeldriver.Actually, I am installing the netCDF-C library from Github (https://github.com/USEPA/CMAQ/blob/master/DOCS/Users_Guide/Tutorials/CMAQ_UG_tutorial_build_library_gcc.md).

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for at least 3 reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should Edit your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.